# YUM group version with tagged RPM versions

Tags: redhat, rpm, packaging, yum

I was wondering whether there are version capabilities with yum groups, correlating group versions with RPM versions.

To give a more concrete example what I would finally like to accomplish for my custom repo is something like this concept:

Let's say we have a grouping (only conceptual at this point) of RPMs (e.g A.rpm, B.RPM) that together constitute a e.g Platform. These rpm have versions so we have A-0.1.rpm, A-0.2.rpm, B-0.1.rpm, B-0.2.rpm etc.

My question is, if it is somehow possible to group the different versions of the individual RPMs in a versioned group. I have done some research on yum groups but it seems that it can't handle versions. Ideally I would like to have something like `yum groupinstall "MyPlastform-0.1"` that installs A-0.1.rpm and B-0.1.rpm and `yum groupinstall "MyPlastform-0.2"` that installs A-0.2.rpm and B-0.2.rpm, or something similar.

Please note that RPMs A and B should not have dependencies with each other.

Can this be accomplished?

Comment: I was wondering that myself. It would be nice to have `A-0.1` and `B-0.1` be `MyPlatform-0.1` while `A-0.1` and `B-0.1.2` be `MyPlatform-0.1.5` or something else arbitrary. But as far as I know, yum does not support versions for groups themselves, or the specific packages in groups. If you find it, I would like to hear about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just shooting blindly here but why don't you use a "virtual package" that essentially depends on other packages with specific versions.  you can version this package as well.

Hence,

MyPlatform-v1.0 is a package that depends on A-0.1 and B0.1
MyPlatform-v1.1 is a package that depends on A-0.2 and B0.1

It's similar to what apt did with the "build-essentials".

Comment: This is how I would handle it. Have a fake RPM that has no files, but `Requires` specific versions of the other RPMs.